# Adding Key and value to each element of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to do this one simple thing that I want to add a key and value to each index of my array i.e.
I have an array like this

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 1
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11198
            [student_name] => Iqra Gabol
            [father_name] => Umer Ishaq Gabol
            [student_email] => iqra.gabol11198@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11199
            [student_name] => Ayehsa Mughal 
            [father_name] => Zahid Iqbal Mughal 
            [student_email] => ayesha.mughal11199@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => zim2love@hotmail.com

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 3
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11202
            [student_name] => Eisha Fahim
            [father_name] => Fahim Ahmed 
            [student_email] => eisha.fahim11202@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => fahimeisha@gmail.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 4
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11204
            [student_name] => Shaanzeh Lodhi
            [father_name] => Sufyan Lodhi
            [student_email] => shaanzeh.lodhi11204@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => sufyan.lodhi@gmail.com

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 5
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11205
            [student_name] => Unaiza Hussain Syed
            [father_name] => Syed Mustafa Hussain
            [student_email] => unaiza.hussain11205@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => syeda.mustafa.hussain@pk.pwc.com
        )


)
```

foreach element I want to get marks for each student and want to add to them like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [student_id] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [student_grno] => 11198
        [student_name] => Iqra Gabol
        [father_name] => Umer Ishaq Gabol
        [student_email] => iqra.gabol11198@habibschools.edu.pk
        [father_email] => 
        [mark_id]      => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [student_id] => 2
        [class_id] => 1
        [student_grno] => 11199
        [student_name] => Ayehsa Mughal 
        [father_name] => Zahid Iqbal Mughal 
        [student_email] => ayesha.mughal11199@habibschools.edu.pk
        [father_email] => zim2love@hotmail.com
              [mark_id]      =>7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [student_id] => 3
        [class_id] => 1
        [student_grno] => 11202
        [student_name] => Eisha Fahim
        [father_name] => Fahim Ahmed 
        [student_email] => eisha.fahim11202@habibschools.edu.pk
        [father_email] => fahimeisha@gmail.com
         [mark_id]      => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [student_id] => 4
        [class_id] => 1
        [student_grno] => 11204
        [student_name] => Shaanzeh Lodhi
        [father_name] => Sufyan Lodhi
        [student_email] => shaanzeh.lodhi11204@habibschools.edu.pk
        [father_email] => sufyan.lodhi@gmail.com
        [mark_id]      => 12
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [student_id] => 5
        [class_id] => 1
        [student_grno] => 11205
        [student_name] => Unaiza Hussain Syed
        [father_name] => Syed Mustafa Hussain
        [student_email] => unaiza.hussain11205@habibschools.edu.pk
        [father_email] => syeda.mustafa.hussain@pk.pwc.com
         [mark_id]      => 2
    )
)
```

mark_id is coming dynamically in a loop.

I used the following code but it is giving me last record only.

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    $val['mark_id'] = get_marks_id();
}
```

Please help. Thanks a lot

Comment: `mark_id is coming dynamically in a loop`-> add that loop code in your question pls

Comment: foreach($students as $key => &$val){
  $val['mark_id'] = $this->student_model->get_subject_result($class_id,$subject_id,$teacher_id,$key);
  }

Comment: unable to understand.... kindly add to question by editing it and elaborate about it

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit more on the issue? I tried your code and it worked perfectly for me. Here is the code I ran:

```
function get_marks_id() {
    return rand(1,10);
}

$arr = [
    [
        'student_id' => 1,
        'class_id' => 1,
        'student_grno' => 11198,
        'student_name' => 'Iqra Gabol',
        'father_name' => 'Umer Ishaq Gabol',
        'student_email' => 'iqra.gabol11198@habibschools.edu.pk',
        'father_email' => '',
    ],
    [
        'student_id' => 2,
        'class_id' => 1,
        'student_grno' => 11199,
        'student_name' => 'Ayehsa Mughal',
        'father_name' => 'Zahid Iqbal Mughal',
        'student_email' => 'ayesha.mughal11199@habibschools.edu.pk',
        'father_email' => 'zim2love@hotmail.com',
    ],
    [
        'student_id' => 3,
        'class_id' => 1,
        'student_grno' => 11202,
        'student_name' => 'Eisha Fahim',
        'father_name' => 'Fahim Ahmed',
        'student_email' => 'eisha.fahim11202@habibschools.edu.pk',
        'father_email' => 'fahimeisha@gmail.com',
    ],
];

foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    $val['mark_id'] = get_marks_id();
}

echo print_r($arr,1);
```

This prints :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 1
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11198
            [student_name] => Iqra Gabol
            [father_name] => Umer Ishaq Gabol
            [student_email] => iqra.gabol11198@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] =>
            [mark_id] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11199
            [student_name] => Ayehsa Mughal
            [father_name] => Zahid Iqbal Mughal
            [student_email] => ayesha.mughal11199@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => zim2love@hotmail.com
            [mark_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 3
            [class_id] => 1
            [student_grno] => 11202
            [student_name] => Eisha Fahim
            [father_name] => Fahim Ahmed
            [student_email] => eisha.fahim11202@habibschools.edu.pk
            [father_email] => fahimeisha@gmail.com
            [mark_id] => 8
        )

)
```

May be you have an issue in your get_marks_id() function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$val['mark_id']`, which is not connected to the array inside a foreach loop, access the array "directly" like this `$arr[$key]`:

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    $arr[$key]['mark_id'] = get_marks_id();
}
```